# OpenRdf Exception when parsing data from DBPedia

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, dbpedia, sesame

I use OpenRdf with Sparql to gather data from DBPedia but I encounter some errors on the following query ran against the DBPedia Sparql endpoint:

```
CONSTRUCT{ 
    ?battle ?relation ?data . 
} 
WHERE{
  ?battle   rdf:type    yago:Battle100953559 ;  
            ?relation   ?data   .  
  FILTER(?relation != owl:sameAs)
}
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 18177
```

*I modified the LIMIT and OFFSET to point out the specific result that provokes the problem.*

The response is this one :

```
@prefix foaf:   <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix ns1:    <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mongol%E2%80%93Jin_Dynasty_War>    foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf   ns1:Mongol–Jin_Dynasty_War .
```

The problem is that the *ns1:Mongol–Jin_Dynasty_War* entity contains a minus sign, therefore I get the following exception when running this query inside a Java application using OpenRdf :

> org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: Expected '.', found '–' [line 3]

**Is there any way to circumvent this problem ?**

Thanks !

Comment: That isn't a minus, that's a dash (`U+2013`) which is an illegal character at that position, so this appears to be a bug in the DBPedia Turtle writer. Your best bet is probably to ask for the output in a different format such as NTriples. I'm not familiar with the OpenRDF APIs, so I'm not sure what your options are there.

Comment: @Alex
Thank you for your hint, I was able to set the output to NTriples, which completely solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help other users who might encounter the same problem, I'll post here the way to set the preferred output format for Graph Queries using OpenRDF v2.7.x.

You need to creat a subclass of [SPARQLRepository](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/repository/sparql/SPARQLRepository.html) to access the HTTPClient (for some reason, the field is `protected`.

```
public class NtripleSPARQLRepository extends SPARQLRepository {
    public NtripleSPARQLRepository(String endpointUrl) {
        super(endpointUrl);
        this.getHTTPClient().setPreferredRDFFormat(RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);
    }
}
```

The you just need to create a new Instance of this class :

```
NtripleSPARQLRepository repository = new NtripleSPARQLRepository(service);
RepositoryConnection connection = new SPARQLConnection(repository);
Query query = connection.prepareQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, "YOUR_QUERY");
```

Comment: Nice workaround. FWIW this method not being publicly exposed is just an oversight on our part: you may notice that in the alternative HTTPRepository class, it _is_ publicly avalable. I've logged an improvement ticket in Sesame's issue tracker to solve this: https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-2193

Answer (score 1):

If you are querying a Virtuoso server, then you are probably encountering sloppiness in the implementation of Virtuoso.  I have seen this when getting XML results (vertical tab in output but only XML 1.0) and most recently in JSON results (\U escape for characters not in Basic Multilingual Plane).